# ng-pick-datetime en Angular suma 3 horas

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

Tengo un ng-pick-datetime en angular 11, que cuando lo guarda, lo envio a la api, guarda 3 horas mas de la seleccionada...

```
<input formControlName="FechaInicio" [owlDateTime]="dt1" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                    <owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>
```

Que deebria configurar para que no me pase? gracias

Comment: ¿En qué formato recibes las fecha?

Comment: No la recibo, la selecciono del datepicker...cuando lo selecciono, lo coloca bien en el input, pero al guardar guarda 3 horas mas, esto tengo configurado tambien, pero no estoy seguro si esta bien
providers: [{provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'sp'},],

Comment: Lo mismo no me he explicado bien: Cuando envías a la API el dato ¿qué recibes, exactamente?

Comment: Si pongo 17 hrs en el datepicker, en la api recibo las 20 hrs, e intentado cambiando  useValue: 'sp' por  useValue: 'ar',  useValue: 'sp_ar' pero sigue sin funcionar, creo que me esta tomando la hora de españa y yo necesito la de argentina

Comment: Usará la hora que tenga el sistema donde se está ejecutando el navegador. Deberías intentar trabajar en UTC

Comment: No se como trabajar en UTC, estoy buscando como cambiar ese useValue a el horario de argentina y q funcione, supongo que debe ser algo sencillo pero no puedo encontrar como resolverlo